# Replay websocket traffic

Tags: websocket, replay

I have a websocket server that is producing a lot of data. I'm only listening, I'm not sending anything.

I'd like to capture the data for a few minutes and store it as test data. Later, I'd like to make a local server to replay this data "realtime", i.e. with the same time between each message (as much as possible).

How do you do this? I'd expected this to be available somewhere out-of-the-box, but maybe I'm not searching for the right keywords.

Comment: Anybody who's reading this, has any answer? I need the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not tested this personally, I will share to help others who come across this post. There is a tool, [server-replay](https://github.com/Stuk/server-replay), which is able to replay network requests from a HAR file.

> Replay server responses from a .har file.
>
> Useful if…
>
> …you want to develop offline and your development server isn't local
> …your development server is very slow and you want to go faster …you
> are developing against an API with rate limits It works by starting a
> proxy server and serving content from a previously saved .har file
> overlayed with files from your local system, configurable with
> mappings.